# iOS NSURLSessionDownloadTask cancels on background in wifi connection

Tags: ios, background, wifi, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am downloading a large file by using NSURLSessionDownloadTask. If device is connected via mobile network it downloads successfuly (while app is on background)

But if the only available connection is wifi, I start the download and send the app to background and lock the screen, it cancels in few minutes (since iOS shuts down wifi for power saving)

How should I keep alive wifi connection (after screen lock) until my download is finished?

thanks in advance.